# Consistent Error on Boot

Tags: windows-10

Every time I boot my computer using Windows 10, I get the following error:
Windows cannot find 'C\Users\Joe\AppData\Roaming\0bc7e4\a30ce3.7ef75d4'.

I would like to find the program that is calling this file.

Comment: Use something like `Autoruns` to determine which application is being started, when you log into the profile, that is calling this non-existant file.

Answer (score 0):

https://download.sysinternals.com/files/Autoruns.zip

another one that MS gobbled up, but it's still good. c.f. process viewer.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.